# If $(1 + \operatorname{cis}x)(1 + \operatorname{cis} 2x) = a + bi$, prove that $a^2 + b^2 = (4\cos x \cos\frac x2)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Could anyone help me with this? I'm stuck.

> If $$(1 + \operatorname{cis}x)(1 + \operatorname{cis} 2x) = a + bi$$ prove that $$a^2 + b^2 = \left(4\cos x \cos\frac x2\right)^2$$

For reference, $\operatorname{cis}x = \cos x + i\sin x$.

I found that 
$$a = 1 + \cos x + \cos2x + \cos3x \quad\text{and}\quad 
b = \sin x + \sin2x + \sin3x$$

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Comment: Please show your efforts on the question to avoid it being closed or heavily downvoted. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults) to know how to ask a good question on this website.

Comment: For starters, note that $a^2+b^2 = |a+bi|^2$. So find the square magnitude of the first expression and see if you can massage it into the last expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note

\begin{align}
a^2+b^2 &= |a + bi|^2 \\
&= |(1 + \operatorname{cis}x)(1 + \operatorname{cis} 2x) |^2\\
 &= |1 + e^{i x}|^2|1 + e^{i 2x}|^2\\
 &= |e^{-\frac x2}+ e^{-\frac x2}|^2 |e^{-i x}+ e^{ ix}|^2\\
 &= |2\cos\frac x2|^2 |2\cos x|^2\\
&= (4\cos x \cos\frac x2)^2
\end{align}

Comment: Could you explain how you got from |1+^|^2 |1+^2|^2 to |^−/2+^−/2|^2 
|^−+^|^2 and then to |2cos/2|^2 |2cos|^2 ? Thank you so much.

Comment: @DanielEspada- note $|1 + e^{i x}|=| e^{i \frac x2} (e^{-i \frac x2}+ e^{i \frac x2})|= | e^{-i \frac x2}+ e^{i \frac x2}|$ and $\cos \frac x2= \frac{e^{-i \frac x2}+ e^{i \frac x2} }2$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$1+\text{cis}2y=1+\cos2y+i\sin2y=2\cos y(\cos y+i\sin y)$$

$$|1+\text{cis}2y|=|2\cos y|\cdot|\cos y+i\sin y|=2|\cos y|$$

$$|1+\text{cis}2y|^2=4|\cos y|^2=4\cos^2y$$